# How do firewall action types happen?

Tags: firewalls

I see some firewall action types in the logs such as client-rst, server-rst etc. Are these action types valid for all firewall vendors? If so, is there a way to get firewall to create these actions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you refer to the `action` field in messages from FortiOS. Based on [this documentation](https://fortinetweb.s3.amazonaws.com/docs.fortinet.com/v2/attachments/d06a7334-1a20-11e9-9685-f8bc1258b856/FortiOS-5.6.7-Log-Reference.pdf) page 38 most values for this field don't actually describe an explicit action taken by the firewall. To cite:

- **Field Name**
  Action (action)
- **Description**
  Status of the session. Uses following definitions:

  - Deny: blocked by firewall policy
  - Start: session start log (special option to enable logging at start of a session). This means firewall allowed.
  - All Others: allowed by Firewall Policy and the status indicates how
    it was closed.
- **Example Field Value**
  action=[deny, accept, start, dns, ip-conn, close, timeout,client-rst, server-rst]

Thus, client-rst and server-rst are not actually actions taken by the firewall. The actual action done is to allow the connection and observe how the connection was closed and log this. For these values it was either closed by a RST from the client or a RST from the server - without any interference by the firewall.

> Are these action types valid for all firewall vendors? If so, is there a way to get firewall to create these actions?

Given that these except for "deny" are not actual "actions" actively done by the firewall in the first place but only passive observations for allowed connections, the question on how they can be created makes no actual sense.

But, can all firewalls let connection pass through and observe what they are doing, like FortiOS is doing here - yes. Will they all log the observed reason for the connection close the same way FortiOS does - no. They might use a different syntax or they might not log the detailed reason at all.

Comment: Not sure but I was trying to understand if it is a part of half-open scanning as it is explained here. "https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html". I am thinking a server-rst if the handshake is originating from the client. and why do you think root-cause-analysis of these traces make no actual sense? maybe I should have asked how they happened instead of can be created. thanks

Comment: @hakkican: *"why do you think root-cause-analysis of these traces make no actual sense?"* - I made no kind of statements on what you should do with the logs, I only explained what they mean.

Comment: I was referring to this statement of yours. "the question on how they can be created makes no actual sense." thanks

Comment: @hakkican: I think we have a different understanding of your question. I interpret it from the perspective of the firewall - and the firewall does not create anything here  but it just observes. You seem to ask what the root cause is, i.e. why the client or server reset the connection in case of these specific 2 log messages. This is worth asking, but  this needs lots of context about your environment.

Comment: I just thought that if I could reproduce this log. what do you mean by context?

Comment: @hakkican: *"what do you mean by context?"* - a firewall controls and protects something: what is this, what are the clients and server which are communicating through the firewall, what is normal traffic and what not, ...